# Insert Arabic data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i tried entering Arabic text and insert it into mysql database using php, when print the row, all rows that in arabic looks like :

???? ???? ???? ?????
Ø§Ø¨Ùˆ Ù†ØµÙŠØ± Ø¹Ù…Ø§Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø±Ø¯Ù† Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø±Ø¯Ù†
Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨Ø¨

i set my database to:
Character set: utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode
Collation: utf8_general_ci

and every field in database:
Character set: utf8
Collation: utf8_general_ci

i need to solve this problem and i appreciate all answers ..

Comment: You should also query `set names utf8` in script to set character set for client.

Comment: Are you using a utf-8 character set when outputting? For example, if you're using HTML, are you using something like this at the top:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`

Comment: i'm new in php, please tell me how to 'set names utf8' in script ?

Comment: In a tool such as PHPmyAdmin, does it renders Arabic text like that?

Comment: ok, thanks @ Mark Ormston, i didn't use it, i put the code u posted at the top and the arabic data displayed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Include the following query in every page of your application `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`
2. Be assured that your web pages are utf-8 encoded by the following meta tag:

Comment: i'm new, where i put this query in the code ??`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`

Comment: Make a PHP file called -for example- inc.php and then place this code inside it, then in every file of your script make sure you included this file.

Comment: please How do that in Java ? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Souad Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this in Java.