# Storing persian\Arabic text in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a column with nickname that it's collection is `utf8-general-ci` and table collection is UTF-8. But persian/arabic text stores in it like below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCWOa.png

How should Solve this problem?

I use this code to save

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO kashef_users(nickname ,username ,email ,ostan ,age ,gender ,sdk ,phonename ,imei ,time ) VALUES ".$data;
```

`$data` contains a a string and everything in data is correct

Comment: Are you sure that's not just a bug in the application that displays it?  If it's really stored wrong, it was most likely inserted wrong, so you'll need to show the code that does the insert as well as any other code that works with the string before it's inserted.

Comment: use `uft-8-persian` rather than `General-ci`

Comment: "Everything in data is correct" — are you sure that `$data` is in the encoding that the database expects?  Your code looks like it may be PHP, and PHP doesn't have native Unicode strings, so you have to make sure the string is in the proper encoding (e.g. UTF-8), and configure the database connection to use the same encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you are using `php` to populate `$data`. So you have to set charset as `UTF8` (i.e. `SET NAMES 'utf-8';`). For example if you were using `mysqli`, your code would be like this:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

Or use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485/1922137) if you were using `PDO` or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16575294/1922137) for deprecated `mysql`. Moreover, do not forget to use `utf8-persian-ci` collection.

In your `html` if you have a form, set the `accept-charset` as `UTF-8`:

```
<form action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```