# the problem to save Persian data in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to save Persian data in MySQL . but when saved in database show like below image. I set utf8 general ci for collation in database and also add header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); in PHP file. but show data like this image.

[image]

Users.php

```
public function updateuser(){

if(isset($_GET['phone']) && isset($_GET['fullname']) && isset($_GET['userPhone']) && isset($_GET['citycode']) && isset($_GET['useraddress']) && isset($_GET['userstatus'])){
    $phone = $_GET['phone'];
    $fullname = $_GET['fullname'];
    $userPhone = $_GET['userPhone'];
    $citycode = $_GET['citycode'];
    $useraddress = $_GET['useraddress'];
    $userstatus = $_GET['userstatus'];

$query = "CALL sp_update_user('$phone','$fullname','$userPhone',$citycode,'$useraddress',$userstatus)";}

$dbcontroller = new DBController();

$this->users = $dbcontroller->executeupdateuserQuery($query);
return $this->users;
}
```

DBController.php

```
function executeupdateuserQuery($query) {

mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');    
$result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);

if ($result)
{
    return "user_updated";
}else{
    return "failed_updated";
}
```

}

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460469/storing-persian-arabic-text-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

when you run mysql connect , you must set

```
   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and for mysqli

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

full example:

```
$connect = mysql_connect($this->hosttype,$this->dbusername,$this->dbpassword)or die('error');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$select = mysql_select_db($this->dbname,$connect)or die('error');
```

Comment: `$mysqli->set_charset()` is exactly the same than `mysqli_set_charset()` and you shouldn't need `SET NAMES 'utf8'` at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the 'Collation' of column to 'utf8mb4_persian_ci' or 'utf8_persian_ci'.

it works.

Answer (score -1):

The data that you insert should have utf8 encoding. You can encode the data using utf8_encode function. For example:

`$fullname = utf8_encode($_GET['fullname'])`;

Comment: This is plain wrong. ISO-8859-1 is a Latin script encoding, it cannot store Persian script at all.